# Recursive update parent and children

Tags: oracle

I have a single table 'category' and once I want to disable a category, I have to check if it´s a parent or a child.
If parent the parent_id is null. If not it has a respective parent_id meaning it´s a child of some other category.

If I receive a parent as param, I have to disable it and it´s children.
If I receive a child as a param, I have to disable it and it´s relative grandchildren.

I need to do it recursively and tried to use a 'connect by' from Oracle but I´m not able to cover both cases: when it´s parent and when it´s child.

```
UPDATE CATEGORY 
SET STATUS = 0 
WHERE EXISTS ( 
SELECT STATUS 
FROM CATEGORY 
START WITH ID = ?1 
CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ID = ID)
```

I saw many examples from different ways but working with 2 tables using joins but I have one single table and don´t know how to achieve it without using joins.

Thank you in advance.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table CATEGORY
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(512 BYTE), 
    "STATUS" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "SHOW_ON_MENU" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "PARENT_ID" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
    "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
REM INSERTING into DATATAXONOMY.CATEGORY
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into DATATAXONOMY.CATEGORY (ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,STATUS,SHOW_ON_MENU,PARENT_ID,CREATED_DATE,LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) values ('LIV95682','TESTE','TESTE','1','1',null,to_timestamp_tz('23.12.21 16:54:55,925000000 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR'),to_timestamp_tz('23.12.21 16:54:55,925000000 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR'));
Insert into DATATAXONOMY.CATEGORY (ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,STATUS,SHOW_ON_MENU,PARENT_ID,CREATED_DATE,LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) values ('LIV13069','TESTE','TESTE','1','1','LIV72783',to_timestamp_tz('23.12.21 17:00:13,075000000 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR'),to_timestamp_tz('23.12.21 17:00:13,075000000 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR'));
Insert into DATATAXONOMY.CATEGORY (ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,STATUS,SHOW_ON_MENU,PARENT_ID,CREATED_DATE,LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) values ('LIV11301','TESTE','TESTE','1','1','LIV95682',to_timestamp_tz('23.12.21 16:58:31,357000000 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR'),to_timestamp_tz('23.12.21 16:58:31,357000000 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR'));
Insert into DATATAXONOMY.CATEGORY (ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,STATUS,SHOW_ON_MENU,PARENT_ID,CREATED_DATE,LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) values ('LIV72783','TESTE','TESTE','1','1','LIV95682',to_timestamp_tz('23.12.21 16:59:32,787000000 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR'),to_timestamp_tz('23.12.21 17:23:57,207000000 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR'));
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index CATEGORY_ID_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY_ID_PK" ON "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table CATEGORY
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" MODIFY ("NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" MODIFY ("DESCRIPTION" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" MODIFY ("STATUS" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" MODIFY ("SHOW_ON_MENU" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" MODIFY ("CREATED_DATE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" MODIFY ("LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" ADD CONSTRAINT "CATEGORY_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Ref Constraints for Table CATEGORY
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" ADD CONSTRAINT "CATEGORY_ID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("PARENT_ID")
      REFERENCES "DATATAXONOMY"."CATEGORY" ("ID") ENABLE;
```

Comment: Please provide `CREATE TABLE` and a few `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Thank you, @Michael

Comment: When you send `'LIV95682'`, you want all 4 set to 0 but when you send `'LIV72783'` you only want that one and `'LIV13069'` set to 0

Comment: Exactly! It should be like this.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you want:

```
merge INTO category a
using (
    select id, :status status
    from category
    start with id=:id
    connect by parent_id = prior id
) b
on (a.id = b.id)
when MATCHED then update
    set a.status = b.status;
```

The `SELECT` clause picks out the `ID`s and their new `STATUS` values that you want to change. The `MERGE` statement does the bulk update.

By using named parameters ( `:id`, `:status` instead of `?` ), I can test in SQL Developer with various values to ensure the code works.

IIRC - the ability to use named parameters in JDBC requires a driver that understands them. (eg the Oracle supplied drivers)